# Select duplicates in a one-to-many child table w/o using unique ID

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a table that stores a user's affiliation status. A user can be a student, faculty, staff, contractor, or any combination. That means for user 105433, he may show up as 4 lines in this table. Unfortunately a recent set of new hires have been inserted twice into the table, so users can have duplicate rows for the same affiliation.

Example rows:

Role_ID  --   Employee_ID   --    Employee Type

10000  --     203398      --      Faculty

10001   --    203398      --      Faculty

10002   --    203398     --       Student

10003   --    203542      --      Staff

10004  --     203542      --      Staff

10005    --   204844      --      Staff

10006    --   204844     --       Student

I want to remove the duplicate rows and be left with:

10000  --     203398      --      Faculty

10002   --    203398     --       Student

10003   --    203542      --      Staff

10005    --   204844      --      Staff

10006    --   204844     --       Student

I have already created a separate table and populated it with all the data that was inserted on the day of duplication if that is useful.

I used this query:

```
select tablename.*

from tablename

inner join (

        select MAX(role_id) as id from tablename GROUP BY employee_id

        )maxid ON tablename.role_id = maxid.id

        order by employee_id
```

This returns only one record per affiliation type per EMPLOYEEID, but I am unsure if I can delete using just this query. Help!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Role_ID, Employee_ID, Employee_Type, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Role_ID, Employee_ID, Employee_Type
HAVING cnt > 1
```

This will give you all of the duplicated records. You can select this into a temp table, then use the results to start deleting records.

Comment: Note: He may have been saying Role_ID should be skipped, but with this he should be able to pick columns.

Comment: That query won't properly execute due to it always returning the value of 1 for count.

Comment: then you've done something wrong, because the `having` clause eliminates all records that have 1/0 counts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure that the data in the columns of your query are unique enough to identify just one record for each possible duplicate, I suggest adding ROWID to the query columns to be sure. e.g.

```
SELECT tablename.*, tablename.ROWID as DEL_ROWID
....
```

The values for ROWID uniquely identify single records. You can even use them in where clauses:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE ROWID IN
  ( SELECT tablename.ROWID
    FROM ...... <same query>  )
```